# What is the best framework to develop rich web applications?

Tags: php, frameworks

I need to know what is the best php framework which provide MVC , and many of custom controls like one's is jsf.

Comment: best is that which is best 4 u..define best...you can try Zend ;)  Look at the comparison chart http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Comment: Zend framework has pre-build ui elements like in GWT.!!

Comment: zend and symfony are both good

Comment: Zend and 'symfony' are outdated and shouldn't be used. Most of the other frameworks have been built by kids with no real knowledge in software architecture. Try [Symfony 2.1](http://symfony.com/doc/master/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html), it is by far the best web framework right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yii is the best one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii.

http://www.yiiframework.com/

It has MVC and you can create custom fields.

Yes it is!

Comment: check http://www.phpframeworks.com/ and select one which is suitable for your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend this PHP Framewkork

http://codeigniter.com/

I made the same question last year, and looking among the ten most famous PHP Framework in the web, this convince in 10 minutes, just read this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/ for 10 minutes and try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

All of the frameworks are the best. They are created by the best people and thus they are available throughout the whole world. Some of the popular ones are;

```
Zend Framework
CakePhp
Simpfony
CodeIgniter
```

It only depend on you, which ever one you like.